# Ubuntu 20 virtual enviromnt and Python 3.7

Tags: python, ubuntu

I upgraded Ubuntu from 18 to 20

I had a package supplied by a third party with the virtual enviroment already setup.

The package requirements were Pyhton 3.7 however with Ubuntu 20 3.7 is removed and I have Python 3.8

Running following command in the virtual enviroment I get this

```
    python --version
    Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
    Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
    Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
    Python 3.7.5
```

What does the error mean ?

What is best approach, install Python 3.7 to run alongside Python 3.8

I have done no changes to the system.

Comment: Python 3.7 reached End Of Life. Why do you want to use it? Doesn't that third party package have a newer version?

Comment: no they only support 3.7. I logged an incident with them and htey said it is not supported on Ubuntu 20 and asked me to go back to Ubuntu 18.  I prefer to stay on Ubuntu 20 and see if I can get the package working. Should I  install another instance of Python running version 3.7.

Comment: They only support an out of date version of Python that doesn't receive security updates? :O

Comment: yes, this is a very large software vendor and not going to mention the name, but I am suprised as to why they only support specific version of Python that is EOL.

Comment: can you use anaconda and `conda create --name p37 python=3.7`?

Comment: That means their software is EOL as well. Because no OS will have Python 3.7 installed. You'll have to download the sources and build Python locally. `asdf install python` does that under the hood.

Comment: Are you sure that 3.7 is the latest version they support? Can you run the package in 3.8?

Comment: Or perhaps you can find a *container* with an older version?

Comment: it does not run in 3.8. This is the error I get    Current thread 0x00007f7d014a6740 (most recent call first):
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f6537ad9740 (most recent call first):

Answer (score 0):

You can install `asdf` and then install whatever version of Python you want with the command `asdf install python 3.7.5`

Please take a look at this https://gist.github.com/rubencaro/888fb8e4f0811e79fa22b5ac39610c9e